# C++ STL set usage

Tags: c++, stl, set, operator-overloading

I have a `std::set` of a structure like the one given below:

```
struct weight{
int y;
int w; 
};
```

with the comparator defined as:

```
bool operator <(const weight&lhs,const weight&rhs) {
    return tie(lhs.y,lhs.w)<tie(rhs.y,rhs.w);
}
```

On what basis will the set be sorted ? And how to sort the the set on a given parameter, also could someone explain the working of function used above?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The set will be ordered using the **[lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)**, meaning, first it compares the y, and if the y are equal, then it compares the w.

**How does this work ?**

[`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) creates a tuple of all the elements which are tied.  [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) provides [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) (used in the tie comparison in your return statement), which are based on the lexicographic order.

**How to use a different order ?**

If you want to use only a specific "parameter" (I understand "member") for the comparison, then either define your `operator<` to use only that member or provide an [ad-hoc comparator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) when constructing your set.

However think twice before defining the comparator.  All elements added to a set must be unique. This uniqueness is determined with the equivalence relation (i.e. two objects are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other). So if your comparator would use only one struct member, say `w`, you would not be able to insert two objects having the same `w` value.

Answer (score 2):

it is preferred in your case to use C++ std::pair.

```
set<pair<int,int> >st;
```

in this case it will be sorted in order of pair.first then pair.second.

**in general:** C++ STL uses comparators for known types (pair orders first then second ,a set of integers are ordered in an ascending order).

but for std::set it uses < operator so when defining a structure to use in std::set you have to override operator <.

Comment: You propose to use a pair instead of the struct.  If the structure is temporary and only for the set (as the original `temp` naming could suggest), then the pair would be valid alternative.  However OP's question suggest that the struct contains more data (the operator used `weight` instead of `temp`, and OP thinks of using only some specific "parameters" for the compare instead of all, which suggest that the struct contains other valuable data). So I'm not sure if pair would really be the way to go in the end.

Comment: @Christophe you are with no doubt correct. but I suggested the pair because it works in many cases, for me I always use set of pairs but that happens when I do Competitive Programming contests. to make it clear in general cases I will go with you.